# Dealing with pointers to structs containing arrays in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, pointers, struct, crash

I am attempting to write a Mac app in Swift that communicates with an iOS device via a library called PeerTalk available from http://rsms.me/peertalk/, so I have been attempting to rewrite the PeerTalk example project in Swift. My Swift rewrite connects and receives messages from the iOS device correctly, but fails to read the messages without crashing.

```
struct PTExampleTextFrame {
    let length: UInt32
    let utf8text: [UInt8]
}

func ioFrameChannel(channel: PTChannel?, didReceiveFrameOfType type: UInt32, tag: UInt32, payload: PTData?) {
    if (type == PTExampleFrameTypeDeviceInfo) {
        let deviceInfo: NSDictionary? = NSDictionary(contentsOfDispatchData: payload!.dispatchData)
        self.presentMessage(NSString(format: "Connected to %@", deviceInfo!.description), isStatus:true)
    } else if (type == PTExampleFrameTypeTextMessage) {

        let textFramePointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<PTExampleTextFrame>(payload!.data)
        let textFrameOptional: PTExampleTextFrame? = textFramePointer.memory
        let textFrame: PTExampleTextFrame

        if textFrameOptional != nil {
            textFrame = textFrameOptional!
            println(ntohl(textFrame.length))
            println(textFrame.utf8text)
        } else {
            println("Recieved bad packet")
        }

    } else if (type == PTExampleFrameTypePong) {
        self.pongWithTag(tag, error:nil)
    }

}
```

The struct and the block below are the only pieces I am having problems with.

```
    let textFramePointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<PTExampleTextFrame>(payload!.data)
    let textFrameOptional: PTExampleTextFrame? = textFramePointer.memory
    let textFrame: PTExampleTextFrame

    if textFrameOptional != nil {
        textFrame = textFrameOptional!
        println(ntohl(textFrame.length))
        println(textFrame.utf8text)
    } else {
        println("Recieved bad packet")
    }
```

When my app receives a message, the ioFrameChannel function is called successfully and prints the proper length of the message sent before crashing with

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x10)
```

when the line printing textFrame.utf8text runs.

Replacing with struct with one that does not include an array successfully prints the UTF-8 representation of the first character of the message as expected.

```
struct PTExampleTextFrame {
    let length: UInt32
    let utf8text: UInt8
}
```

The above works in Objective C as written in the example project below

```
//PTExampleProtocol.h
typedef struct _PTExampleTextFrame {
  uint32_t length;
  uint8_t utf8text[0];
} PTExampleTextFrame;

//PTAppDelegate.m
- (void)ioFrameChannel:(PTChannel*)channel didReceiveFrameOfType:(uint32_t)type tag:(uint32_t)tag payload:(PTData*)payload {
  //NSLog(@"received %@, %u, %u, %@", channel, type, tag, payload);
  if (type == PTExampleFrameTypeDeviceInfo) {
    NSDictionary *deviceInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfDispatchData:payload.dispatchData];
    [self presentMessage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Connected to %@", deviceInfo.description] isStatus:YES];
  } else if (type == PTExampleFrameTypeTextMessage) {
    PTExampleTextFrame *textFrame = (PTExampleTextFrame*)payload.data;
    textFrame->length = ntohl(textFrame->length);
    NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:textFrame->utf8text length:textFrame->length encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [self presentMessage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"[%@]: %@", channel.userInfo, message] isStatus:NO];
  } else if (type == PTExampleFrameTypePong) {
    [self pongWithTag:tag error:nil];
  }
}
```

I expect the crash has something to do with Swift not knowing when the array stops. How could I read the entire message in Swift without my application crashing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I learn more about Swift, it appears that the ObjC struct with the 0 length array is imported into swift as a zero tuple. Fixed length arrays import as tuples since fixed length arrays don't exist in Swift. I would assume that a pointer to the zero tuple would work for this purpose; however, I haven't tested as instead of using this protocol, I just rewrote the iOS app and completely changed the protocol to not even need this weird structure.

Comment: You have to change the struct to not be memory equivalent as the one from the protocol, so you have to do a conversion to the other memory format if you intend to send it elsewhere. You do something along the lines of this to get the array of bytes. `UnsafeBufferPointer<UInt8>(baseAddress: payload.data + sizeof(UInt32), count: Int(UnsafePointer<UInt32>(payload.data).pointee))` You might want to clean it up a bit or split it into multiple lines or something. I'm not entirely sure that's valid Swift as I don't have a copy of Xcode next to me right now, but hopefully you get the gist.

Comment: Thanks @deaton.dg.